# discord import for python (unable to resolve 'discord'. IntelliSense may be missing for this module)

Tags: python, discord

I'm a little ignorant when it comes to python because I recently started teaching myself it in order to make a discord bot. As a result, I have no idea why the import won't work. Any ideas how to fix?

This is an example code from online which I have been trying to manipulate in order to fit the roll of my bot:

```
import discord
client = discord.Client()
@client.event
    async def on_ready():
    print("The bot is ready!")
    await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name="Making a    bot"))
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content == "Hello":
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "World")
client.run(token)
```

Comment: Sounds like you installed it to a different Python environment than the one you're developing in. Are you using an IDE?

Comment: Can you show the  code?

Comment: @AGhanima I edited the question and added the code

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I am using Microsoft visual studio to run it

Comment: There should be indentations in the function definitions.

Comment: @Heikki Sorry, I didn't format it correctly when putting it on stack overflow but there are indentations in visual studio. just fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You should run the following command in cmd  to install the library

```
python3 -m pip install -U discord.py
```